# SICP chapter 3: How does `set!` works when its first arguement is a subexpression

Tags: sicp, mit-scheme

I don't understand the behavior of `set!` when its first argument is a sub-expression. For example, what does`(set! (sub-expression x) y)` do?

The main reason I'm asking this is because `append!` relies on the fact that running a `set!` on `(sub-expression x)` will change `x` itself.

```lisp
(define (append! x y)
    (set-cdr! (last-pair x) y)
     x))
```

where `last-pair` is defined as:

```lisp
(define (last-pair x)
  (if (null? (cdr x)) x (last-pair (cdr x))))
```

I can't seem to understand why `set-cdr!` works that way.

Comment: First you evaluate the sub-expression, the resulting value is a cons-cell; then you call set-cdr! on this cell

Comment: @coredump Yes that's clear, but why does this change the original value `x`?

Comment: x references the same structure as before, ie. the same chain of cons cells, up to the last pair; set-cdr! is an operation that changes the *content* of an existing cell, which is also why by convention it ends with a bang! the operation is said to be destructive because the previous content the cell (and by extension of x) no longer exists.